# How to deserealize undefined and nested Hashtable structure with json.net

Tags: json.net

How to deserealize undefined and nested Hashtable structure with **json.net**?
for example:
@"{"a" : {"b" : 1}}"

```
Hashtable data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Hashtable>(json_str)
```

returns *Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject* at data["a"], instead *Hashtable*

Answer (score 0):

If the structure of the JSON is not known ahead of time, and the JSON does not contain any type metadata to help Json.Net figure things out, then Json.Net has no choice but to use JTokens (JObject, JProperty, JArray, JValue, etc.) to deserialize things into.  That is how it is designed to work.

If you prefer to work with Hashtables, it should be possible to convert the JToken object graph into a nested Hashtable structure after the deserialization, but I'm not sure you gain much by doing that.  You would be better off just learning how to read the data out of the JTokens directly.  (You would have to do so in order to do the conversion anyway.)